# How to find differences in a javascript collection across multiple version?

Tags: javascript, diff

I'm trying to output a list of items and their previous version's value, based on a collection of JSON values.

I've tried to [recreate the code](http://jsfiddle.net/bphzpLxL/7/) I have at work from memory, but it's not working.

What algorithm should I use to look back through the versions, and find the previous item and output a diff on it?

This is what I've got so far, but it's fairly broken:

```
function findPriceChanges(data){
    var changeSet = _.keys(data)

  // for each change set
  return _.each(changeSet, function(change){
    // map over each change set until you find the same key
    return _.map(change, function(itemIDInChange, index, list){
        var previousVersion = change.version;
        do{
        // descend through the items until you run out of items 
        // or we find an item that matches
        previousVersion -= 1;
        var previousChangeitem = _.where(data[previousVersion], {id:itemIDInChange});
      }while(previousVersion !== 0 && !previousChangeitem)
      return {
        old: previousChangeitem.price || null,
        new: change[itemIDInChange].price,
        name: change[itemIDInChange].price
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Is this the right sort of approach? How do I fix this to give me the desired output?